# Laravel use HTML::image for background-image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

how to use `HTML::image()` for inline styled with `background-image` such as this html tags:

this line is into my main.blade.php file and that is main skeletion of my template.

```
<div style="height: 45px;background-image:url('../public/images/header_pattern2.png');border-radius: 5px;position:relative">
```

in main.blade.php my page view correct template. but after redirect such as `login.blade.php` images do not show. but after switch to index i do not have a problem.

in public directory i have `images`,`js`,`css` folders and my public is this:

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/..',
```

i can remove public directory. how to convert `background-image:url('../public/images/header_pattern2.png');` to blade `HTML::image()` tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this:

```
<div style="height: 45px;background-image:url('{{ asset('images/header_pattern2.png') }}');border-radius: 5px;position:relative">
```

**Update:**

Actually, `HTML::image()` generates an `<img />` tag and you are using a div, if you want to use this using `HTML::div()` then you may create a [custom macro](http://laravel.com/docs/html#custom-macros).

**Update:** I've created this `custom macro`:

```
/**
 * Param $attr : An array of styles
 * Param $html : HTML content for div
 * Returns HTML DIV
 */
HTML::macro('divWithBG', function($attr = array(), $html = ''){
    $style = 'style = ';
    foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
        if($key == 'background-image') $style .= $key.':url(\'' . $value .'\');';
        else $style .= $key . ':' . $value .';';
    }
return "<div $style >$html</div>";
});
```

You may use it in `blade view` as:

```
{{ HTML::divWithBG(array('background-image' => asset('images/8_big.jpg'), 'height' => '45px', 'border-radius'=>'5px', 'position'=>'relative' )) }}
```

Output:

```
<div style="background-image:url('http://blog.dev/images/8_big.jpg');height:45px;border-radius:5px;position:relative;"></div>
```

Rendered Output:

[image]

Comment: your defined macro could not generate correct style.`{{ HTML::div(array('background-image' => asset('images/header_pattern2.png'), 'height' => '45px', 'border-radius'=>'5px', 'position'=>'relative' )) }}` generate: `<div style="background-image:url('http://localhost/alachiq/images/header_pattern2.png');background-image:http://localhost/alachiq/images/header_pattern2.png;height:45px;border-radius:5px;position:relative;"></div>` html

Comment: @TuxWorld, It works, actually I missed an `else`, most probably it was a typo but fixed it and works but if you don't provide any `HTML` as second argument then it probably won't be visible.

Comment: i dont need to have `HTML` for that.

Comment: Well, it depends on you but it works now, even without `HTML` but provide a dimension, tested it.

Comment: yes. thank. how to register that to core of laravel without using that on `route.php` ?

Comment: Well, you may use a service provider but you may also keep it in a separate file, for example `app/macros.php` and paste the code with other macros (if available) and include it from the `global.php`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49221/discussion-between-tuxworld-and-sheikh-heera)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to solve it. This is assuming that the image exist.

```
public function inline($path)
{      
    $filetype = File::type( $path );
    $response = Response( File::get($path), 200 );
    $response->header('Content-Type', $filetype);
    return $response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked

```
 background: url('{{asset('uploads/avatars/'.$employee->avatar)}}')
```